# Regex to get consecutive capitalized words with one or more words doesn't work

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get consecutive capitalized words with one or more but it looks like it doesn't work for me.

```
def extract(string):
    return re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]*(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)*)', string)
```

Here's my test case

```
def test_extract_capitalize_words(self):
    keywords = extract('This is New York and this is London')
    self.assertEquals(['New York', 'London'], keywords)
```

It only captures `New York` and not `London`

Comment: Of course not. `London` is not followed by a space and a capital letter, which is what the `(?=\s[A-Z])` lookahead expression requires.

Comment: You said you're looking for **consecutive capitalized words** - why would you expect London to show up in the results ?

Comment: Sorry my title is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a succinct option:

```
\b(?:[A-Z][a-z]*\b\s*)+
```

- If you are using the `regex` module instead of `re`, consider using `\p{Lu}` and `\p{Ll}` for Unicode uppercase and lowercase letters instead of `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]`.
- The `\b` at the start and middle are word boundaries, and are there to avoid matching words like `McBain` or `GOP`. If you want to match these' remove the second `\b`.
- `[a-z]*` is used for allowing single-letter words, like `A` or `I`. Use `+` if you don't want them.
- The pattern captures an additional space at the end of the match. You can use `(?<!\s)` to explicitly remove that space. A feature like `\>` (word end) would have been more elegant, but Python (and most flavors) don't support it.

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/sT1rS4/1

Answer (score 0):

This would match the consecutive captitalized word or the capitalized word followed by an end of the line boundary.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'This is New York and this is London'
>>> re.findall(r'\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b(?:(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]*\b)+|$)', s)
['New York', 'London']
```

Comment: I think `\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]*\b)*` would be enough - I don't think the end of the string (`$`) is meaningful: